# AlphaImageLoader does not work Label tag

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I experienced problem with `AlphaImageLoader` filter applied on tag `<label>` in Internet Explorer 7

Here is my HTML code:

```
<label class="yes-radio-small" for="subtrack">&nbsp;</label>
```

Here is CSS:

```
.yes-radio-small{
   background-image: none;
   -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='images/yes-radio.png',sizingMethod='scale')";
   filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader( src='images/yes-radio.png', sizingMethod='scale');

   padding-left: 60px;
   padding-bottom: 17px;
   padding-top: 22px;
   padding-right: 22px;
}
```

If I change `<label`> to `<button>`, it works fine and backround exists and scaled as needed.

Can anyone explain why this happened and how can it be fixed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution - I have just wrapped `<label>` with `<div>` tag

`<label class="yes-radio-small" for="subtrack">&nbsp;</label>`

Hope it will be useful for someone